# How to release memory in Spritekit game after SKScene ends

Tags: memory-management, ios8

I am trying to make a game with 10 levels. Everytime I load the page and its corresponding SKScene, the memory usage increases, while when I leave the page & scene, i make scene = nil, yet the memory decreases only a little bit, not fully. 10 levels consume high memory and if I carry on playing all the levels, again, app may crash due to memory pressure. How can I release all the memory immediately after leaving the scene?

Comment: preload the texture every time you load a new level and remove all the reference when user completed that level even textureAtlas reference too.spritekit holds textures in memory every even setting scene =nil does not remove all texture from memory for that your have to remove textureAtlas from the memory by setting it nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this when the scene ends:

```
[self removeAllActions];
[self removeAllChildren];
```

I found it helps with strange problems that can occur on scene changes and memory issues.

Comment: Thanks, but I have used both of them, but still the memory doesn't drop down abruptly, the problem will occur if I keep on repeating the levels, as the memory will rise consistently.